# Why wasn't Alice sent to Raccoon City Hive right after Extension?

Tags: resident-evil

Wouldn't it be more logical for the Red Queen to send Alice and her Clones to Raccoon City to get the Antivirus right after she killed the Clone of Isaacs, rather than sacrifice them by attacking random Bases? At the end of Extinction Alice is fully buffed, has an Army of Clones and even access to vehicles capable of bringing them to Tokyo...

Comment: There's logic in these movies?  Where?  It needs to be shot, in the head, repeatedly.